# Accessing a controller method from javascript file(MVC3)

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a method in the controller which returns a JASON output as given below.

```
  public JsonResult GetJSONDateData()
    {

        JsonResult startDate = new JsonResult();

        var Mystartdate = "02/01/2011";
        startDate.Data = Mystartdate;
        startDate.JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet;

        return startDate;

    }
```

And I try to access this method in javascript using

```
 var query = '';
query = getDomainURL() + "/ControlelrName/GetJSONDateData";
    jQuery.ajaxSetup({ async: false });
var startDate = '';  //The max size if nothing is coming from config...
$.post(query, function (response) {
    startDate = response;
});
jQuery.ajaxSetup({ async: true });
```

IS there anything wrong in my functions? I am not getting anything in the response. Pls help

Thanks,
Adarsh

Comment: Please use Firebug, Fiddler or a similar tool to inspect what request and response is sent to and received from the server. Then add it to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you are making a GET request and it's not allowed.

In your action method try the following:

```
 return JSON(startDate, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: Ok it turns out that my project was referring to a old dll somehow! and my changes in the controller werent reflected!, Hence I wasnot getting the required output, Once the dll was deleted and a rebuild was done, the above code works fine, Sorry to bother guys.